# Strange server logs

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking

I'm seeing a lot of this in my server logs

```
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=1126 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=1106
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=194  TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=174
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=69   TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=49
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=60   TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=40
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=104  TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=84
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=138  TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=118
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=207  TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=187
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=60   TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=40
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=104  TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=84
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=138  TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=118
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=207  TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=187
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=60   TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=40
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=104  TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=84
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=138  TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=118
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=207  TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=187
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=236  TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=216
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=69   TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=49
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=190  TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=170
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=843  TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=823
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=973  TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=953
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=236  TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=216
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=69   TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=49
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=973  TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=953
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=1126 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=1106
IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<my external ip> DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=69   TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=49
```

These are packets that are being dropped by the INPUT chain. These look like multicast DNS packets, but they're coming in eth0, which is WAN and connected directly to my router. Did I somehow misconfigure something such that LAN mDNS packets are being routed to eth0? Or is this a really creative attack?

Comment: What interface is `<my external ip>` on?

Comment: `<my external ip>` is the address of `eth0`. The netmask is `255.255.224.0`, which I find somewhat odd. Provided to me by my ISP via DHCP.